# Comparison of integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Under what conditions on $f$ can we conclude the following inequality:

> $$\left(\int_a^b f \, \mathrm{d}x\right)^2 \leq \int_a^b f^2 \, \mathrm{d}x.$$

Cauchy-Schwarz looked appealing at first:
$$\left(\int_a^b fg \, \mathrm{d}x \right)^2 \leq \left(\int_a^b f^2 \, \mathrm{d}x\right)\left(\int_a^b g^2 \, \mathrm{d}x\right).$$
Setting $g \equiv 1$, we get
$$\left(\int_a^b f \, \mathrm{d}x \right)^2 \leq (b-a)\left(\int_a^b f^2 \, \mathrm{d}x\right),$$
so if $b - a \leq 1$, we are done. But what about for more general intervals? I think the answer lies in a more clever substitution/manipulation. Feel free to cite as many powerful inequalities as you want. All integration is done in the Riemann sense, but answers with Lebesgue are welcome.

Comment: If you consider the case $f(x) = 1$, you will see that the condition $b-a \le 1$ is necessary.  The only fix is to restrict what functions you allow.

Comment: That is my question though -- can we state any general necessary or sufficient conditions for this to hold? $f(x) = 0.5$ on the interval $[0,2]$ breaks this inequality, so I am guessing it has something to do with how close $f$ or the integral is to 1.

Comment: This inequality is called Feng Qi inequality you may see some works about it here http://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/084_04_JIPAM/084_04.pdf         http://www.emis.de/journals/DM/v13-1/art2.pdf                                                  Also you may google it to find more

Comment: Are you asking for conditions just on $f$ so that the inequality is true for all values of $a$ and $b$, or for combinations of conditions on $f$ and $a$ and $b$ (i.e., statements like "for $f$ like such-and-such, it works as long as $a$ and $b$ are such-and-such")?

Comment: I was asking anything really. Just wanted insight into the problem. From the recently posted answer, I now understand what @StephenMontgomery-Smith was saying in his original comment, so I believe the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $f \in L^2[a,b]$ we have, $$\left(\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f \, \mathrm{d}x\right)^2 \leq \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f^2 \, \mathrm{d}x.$$ by Jensen's Inequality for integrals. ($\phi(x)=x^2$ is convex.)

This implies, $$\left(\int_a^b f \, \mathrm{d}x\right)^2 \leq (b-a)\int_a^b f^2 \, \mathrm{d}x.$$
Therefore, if we have $(b-a) \leq 1$ then we have the original inequality. On the other hand suppose the inequality hold for all $f \in L^2[a,b]$ then $f(x)=1$ yields $(b-a)^2 \leq (b-a) \implies (b-a) \leq 1$.

Hence, the condition $(b-a)\leq 1$ is sufficient and necessary.

$\textbf{Edit}:$
The equality here occurs if and only if $f$ is constant. So, we should have strict inequality if $f$ is non-constant.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.  The second part of your answer says that if the inequality holds for *all* $f$, then $b-a \leq 1$ is necessary.  But the question is whether you can specify conditions on $f$.  There are certainly *some* functions for which the inequality holds true for some $b - a > 1$, and I think that's what the question is asking about.

Comment: I actually have a condition on $f$: $f \in L^2[a,b]$. What I have shown is that under this condition on $f$ we are forced choose $a<b$ such that $b-a<1$.